# og:description not pulling contents from meta

Tags: facebook, metadata

I am recently experiencing problems with metadata for Facebook and I was wondering if any other EE user has experienced the same.

In principle, the code should be fine and was actually working till not long ago. At some point it stopped doing so and FB scraps no content for og:description (and neither for meta:description for that matter). I thought it might have been aproblem with my descriptions starting with the

tag so I installed streeng and did this:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="{pages_title}">
<meta property="og:description" {exp:streeng allowed="none"}content="{pages_summary}"{/exp:streeng}>
{if picture}
<meta property="og:image" content="{picture}">
{if:else}
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.ecfr.eu/page/-/logoxfb.png?v=1415186136948">
<meta property="og:url" content="{url_title_path='article'}">
```

but still no result. All other meta works.. any idea?

Comment: When you view source on your rendered template what is the html output? Do you get any helpful info from the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) for that URL?

Comment: Hi. No, not really. It just does not pull whatever comes into the 'description' quotes `<meta property="og:title" content="Balkan genocides without genocidal intentions">
<meta property="og:description" content="
">`

But if you check here [link](http://www.ecfr.eu/article/commentary_emma_bonino_secular_people_of_the_world_unite_against_intoleranc) it is in the meta (with the p tag in this case but the result is the same)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this will sound silly but have you tried changing your quotation marks within the EE tag to single quotes.
I run into this issue all the time even though it 'looks' like it shouldn't be an issue.

```
<meta property="og:description" {exp:streeng allowed='none'}content="{pages_summary}"{/exp:streeng}>
```

I always use single quotes ( ' ) within an EE tag since HTML uses double ones ( " ).

Comment: That worked!! So strange cause it did get all the other information but not  that very line, just changed it to '{exp:streeng allowed="none"}content='{pages_summary}'{/exp:streeng}' and it's been found by the debugger. Thanks a lot :D

Comment: Nice answer Cheyney! Storing this in my memory.

Comment: You're welcome. But try the quotes around the other way. Use double quotes for the html part and singles inside the EE tags. You will run into trouble in other places if you don't sitck to that convention.

<meta property="og:description" {exp:streeng allowed='none'}content="{pages_summary}"{/exp:streeng}>

Comment: PS: I mean all EE tags everywhere use single quotes inside them.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook caches data so if you're testing a specific URL and not seeing the results as you'd expect, it's most likely their cache is storing incorrect information.

You can force clear the Facebook cache for a specific url using their [**Debugger tool**](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip but that is the problem, the description content is not pulled in the debugger, so it's not a cache problem. interestingly enough, sometimes Facebok ends up using the description even if I can't see it in the scraped code.

Comment: Is it rendering to your page's source code?

Comment: yes, it does, that's what baffles me 

`<meta content="article" property="og:type">
<meta content="Note from Berlin: Lessons from Munich" property="og:title">
<meta content="<p> As Europe pushes for negotiation over Ukraine, the Munich Security Conference showed the depth of division not only between Russia and the West, but between the Western partners as well.</p> " property="og:description">`

in this version it has the <p> tags in - I thought that was the problem so I tried to remove them with Streeng (add-on) on the test web we have. It does remove the tags but I get the same problem.